mavros ./install_geographiclib_datasets.sh is not working
I am using px4 and mavros for drone simulation. I have the following mavros launch file px4.launch
<launch>
    <arg name="fcu_url" default="udp://127.0.0.1:8888" />
    <arg name="gcs_url" default="" />
    <arg name="tgt_system" default="1" />
    <arg name="tgt_component" default="1" />
    <arg name="log_output" default="screen" />
    <arg name="fcu_protocol" default="v2.0" />
    <arg name="respawn_mavros" default="false" />

    <include file="$(find mavros)/launch/node.launch">
    <arg name="pluginlists_yaml" value="$(find mavros)/launch/px4_pluginlists.yaml" />
        <arg name="config_yaml" value="$(find mavros)/launch/px4_config.yaml" />

        <arg name="fcu_url" value="$(arg fcu_url)" />
    <arg name="gcs_url" value="$(arg gcs_url)" />
        <arg name="tgt_system" value="$(arg tgt_system)" />
    <arg name="tgt_component" value="$(arg tgt_component)" />
        <arg name="log_output" value="$(arg log_output)" />
    <arg name="fcu_protocol" value="$(arg fcu_protocol)" />
        <arg name="respawn_mavros" default="$(arg respawn_mavros)" />
    </include>
</launch>

I am getting the following error
[FATAL] [1732731962.964419171]: UAS: GeographicLib exception: File not readable /usr/share/GeographicLib/geoids/egm96-5.pgm | Run install_geographiclib_dataset.sh script in order to install Geoid Model dataset! ================================================================================REQUIRED process [mavros-1] has died! process has finished cleanly log file: /home/mubashir/.ros/log/018d1878-ace8-11ef-97a6-cf75c9b307ce/mavros-1*.log Initiating shutdown
when I run sudo bash /opt/ros/noetic/lib/mavros/install_geographiclib_datasets.sh I waited more than an hour but nothing happened I have a stable internet connection, and the following appeared on the screen the last hour Installing GeographicLib geoids egm96-5 
